# BASH formatting output of cpuinfo

Tags: html, bash, formatting

I'm writing a script to grab a bunch of information on servers that we have an output the results to a html file. It's working up to a point. I'm getting stuck when I grab the cpuinfo. It grabs it and dumps it where I want but it's not formatted as it is in the shell. I've tried using sed but maybe I wasn't using it all that well, and I've tried columns but nothing seems to work. I keep getting a blob. Please see my code below and how it's outputting now....

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define global variables
HOSTNAME=`uname -n`
TITLE="System Information for "
CPUINFO=`cat /proc/cpuinfo`


cat <<- EOF > /tmp/grab_server_info.html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    $TITLE $HOSTNAME
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>$HOSTNAME</h1>
    <p>Last run on $(date +"%c") by $USER</p>
    <h3>UPTIME</h3>
    <p>$(uptime)</p>
    <h3>CPU Information</h3>
    <p>$CPUINFO</p>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Ends up looking like this:

[image]

Of course what I'm looking for is something more inline with what you'd get if you ran cat /proc/cpuinfo in the shell. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [`<pre>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre):

> The HTML `<pre>` element represents preformatted text which is to be presented exactly as written in the HTML file. The text is typically rendered using a non-proportional ("monospace") font. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as written.

```
<h3>CPU Information</h3>
<pre>$CPUINFO</pre>
```

Example:

```html
<pre>
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
</pre>
```

Alternatively you could process the output to generate an actual HTML table from it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<pre>` is certainly the simplest way - it also copes better with rogue symbols than my suggestion, which just tends to look better, when it works: decorate each line of output from $CPUINFO with table tags to get a more flexible layout:

- Inject `<table border = "1">` before
- The start of each line becomes `<tr><td>`
- The colon becomes `</td><td>`
- The end of line becomes `</td></tr>`
- inject `</table>` after

This is a quick bit of sed, such as:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo| sed -E 's/^([^:]*):(.*)$/<tr><td>\1<\/td><td>\2<\/td><\/tr>/'
```

If you are concerned about non-printables in the body text, then you can enclose each subclause with `<pre>` tags.

Note also that if you have multiple processors the list can be very long (80 processors+), and every field the same, except cpu MHz, so you could consider combining them into more columns where they do differ. That gets to be quite hairy html, though.

Comment: Hi Gem,

Thanks. The <pre> tags did it, but as you mentioned...adding the HTML tags around the work would be even better for flexibility as the format is still not just the way I need it. Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with SED. After researching I'm at a bit of a loss. This is the best I've come up with and I'm fairly certain it's not working right. sed 's/:/</td><td>/g;s/\A/<table border = "1">/g;s/\Z/</table>/g;s/^/<tr><td>/g;s/$/</td></tr>/g' 
Additionally, I'm not quit certain were to place this in the script. Would it be just before the HTML block?

Comment: I added the one-shot sed statement to the answer... hopefully what you need. `<table>$seddedcpuinfo</table>` effectively replaces `<p>$CPUINFO</p>`. Remember that html doesn't give a fig about your file indentation, so that is up to you.